# How to define an antisymmetric symbol?

Tags: functions, assumptions, tensors

I want to work with linear expressions involving the formal symbol $w[a_1,...,a_n]$, and I would like Mathematica to know that expressions such as

```
w[a,b,d] + w[a,d,b] = 0
```

i.e. that the symbol `w` is antisymmetric with respect to the swap of any of its entries.
What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a variation of Roman's answer that doesn't require the application of [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll) to simplify things:

```
a_w /; !OrderedQ @ Unevaluated @ a := Signature[Unevaluated[a]]Sort[Unevaluated[a]]
```

Your example:

```
w[a, b, d] + w[a, d, b]
```

> 0

Another possibility is to use the symbolic tensor capabilities of Mathematica. For example:

```
TensorReduce[
    w + TensorTranspose[w, {1, 3, 2}],
    Assumptions -> w ∈ Arrays[{n, n, n}, Complexes, Antisymmetric[{1,2,3}]]
]
```

> 0

Comment: Carl, can you please add a little bit of explanation on your use of `Unevaluated` in your first solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by simplifying every mention of `w` to its sorted form:

```
w[a, b, d] + w[a, d, b] /. W_w :> Signature[W]*Sort[W]
```

> 0

```
{w[a, b, d], w[a, d, b], w[b, a, d], w[b, d, a], w[d, a, b], w[d, b, a]} /.
  W_w :> Signature[W]*Sort[W]
```

> {w[a, b, d], -w[a, b, d], -w[a, b, d], w[a, b, d], w[a, b, d], -w[a, b, d]}